# Old manga about a boy and girl who die in an accident, and are given a week by God to decide which one should be resurrected

Tags: story-identification, manga

I am looking for a manga where a boy accidently falls on a girl from the roof of a building. Both die on the spot.

They meet God, who gives them a chance to decide who will be resurrected; the choice must be made in a week.

They are sent back to Earth before the deadline, however, during that time they are linked by emotions; they can feel what the other is feeling and they end up falling in love.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. If anyone correctly identifies the manga you're looking for, you can mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 8):

Pretty sure this is ***[Half & Half](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=36231)***.

From Baka-Updates:

> **Nagakawa Shinichi and Sanada Yuuki both get involved in an accident and die together, but they are given a chance to live again. A voice lets them survive for seven more days. However, after the time limit, one of the two must die again.
> Also, their lives will be shared, including emotions (guilt) and physical sensations (pain).** They are told not to leave the other's side, else both of them will die. Now, with each of them wanting to save his/her own life, how will the next seven days of non-separation be like? Will they get along?

[image]

[image]